# One2many field issue Odoo 10.0

Tags: postgresql, orm, odoo-9, odoo-10, one2many

I have this very weird issue with One2many field.
First let me explain you the scenario...

I have a One2many field in `sale.order.line`, below code will explain the structure better

```
class testModule(models.Model):
    _name = 'test.module'

    name = fields.Char()


class testModule2(models.Model):
    _name = 'test.module2'

    location_id = fields.Many2one('test.module')
    field1 = fields.Char()
    field2 = fields.Many2one('sale.order.line')


class testModule3(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    test_location = fields.One2many('test.module2', 'field2')
```

**CASE 1:**
Now what is happening is that when i create a new **sales order**, i select the `partner_id` and then add a `sale.order.line` and inside this line i add the One2many field `test_location` and then i save.

**CASE 2:**
Create new **sales order**, select `partner_id` then add `sale.order.line` and inside the `sale.order.line` add the `test_location` line [close the sales order line window]. Now after the entry **before hitting save** i change a field say `partner_id` and then click save.

**CASE 3:**
this case is same as *case 2* but with the addition that i again change the `partner_id` field [changes made total 2 times first of case2 and then now], then i click on save.

***RESULTS***

*CASE 1* works fine.

*CASE 2* has a issue of

```
odoo.sql_db: bad query: INSERT INTO "test_module2" ("id", "field2", "field1", "location_id", "create_uid", "write_uid", "create_date", "write_date") VALUES(nextval('test_module2_id_seq'), 27, 'asd', ARRAY[1, '1'], 1, 1, (now() at time zone 'UTC'), (now() at time zone 'UTC')) RETURNING id

ProgrammingError: column "location_id" is of type integer but expression is of type integer[]
LINE 1: ...VALUES(nextval('test_module2_id_seq'), 27, 'asd', ARRAY[1, '...
```

now for this case i put a debugger on create/write method of `sale.order.line` to see waht the values are getting passed..

```
values = {u'product_uom': 1, u'sequence': 0, u'price_unit': 885, u'product_uom_qty': 1, u'qty_invoiced': 0, u'procurement_ids': [[5]], u'qty_delivered': 0, u'qty_to_invoice': 0, u'qty_delivered_updateable': False, u'customer_lead': 0, u'analytic_tag_ids': [[5]], u'state': u'draft', u'tax_id': [[5]], u'test_location': [[5], [0, 0, {u'field1': u'asd', u'location_id': [1, u'1']}]], 'order_id': 20, u'price_subtotal': 885, u'discount': 0, u'layout_category_id': False, u'product_id': 29, u'price_total': 885, u'invoice_status': u'no', u'name': u'[CARD] Graphics Card', u'invoice_lines': [[5]]}
```

in the above values `location_id` is getting passed like `u'location_id': [1, u'1']}]]` which is not correct...so for this i correct the issue in code and the update the values and pass that...

*CASE 3*
if the user changes the field say 2 or more than 2 times then the values are

```
values = {u'invoice_lines': [[5]], u'procurement_ids': [[5]], u'tax_id': [[5]], u'test_location': [[5], [1, 7, {u'field1': u'asd', u'location_id': False}]], u'analytic_tag_ids': [[5]]}
```

here

```
u'location_id': False
```

**MULTIPLE CASE**

if the user does *case 1* the on the same record does *case 2* or *case 3* then sometimes the line will be saved as `field2 = Null or False` in the database other values like `location_id` and `field1` will have data but not `field2`

***NOTE: THIS HAPPENS WITH ANY FIELD NOT ONLY PARTNER_ID FIELD ON HEADER LEVEL OF SALE ORDER***

I tried debugging myself but couldn't find the reason why this is happening .